# Parse GraphQL query to find fields to be able to prefetch_related?

Tags: django, graphene-python, graphene-django

When using `DjangoListObjectType` from graphene_django_extras, I can define a custom `qs` property on a `SearchFilter`.

The qs function has the object as its only argument, and through that I can get the request, and in turn the query string which includes the queried fields.

Before hacking together my own parser to get these fields, am I going about this the wrong way? Or is there something else out there?

The idea is to have quite a rigid approach, as we have 7 types of paginated list types with fields that result in a few unnecessary database hits, so we want to prefetch a few fields.

Graphene has a dataloader approach which kind of looks right, but more complicated than just prefetching them at the qs stage.

---

Re the dataloader approach, I tried something like this

```
class UserLoader(DataLoader):
    def batch_load_fn(self, keys):
        users = {user.id: user for user in User.objects.filter(id__in=keys)}
        return Promise.resolve([users.get(user_id) for user_id in keys])


user_loader = UserLoader()

class BookType(DjangoObjectType):
    ...
    author = graphene.Field(UserType)

    def resolve_author(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return user_loader.load(self.author.id)
```

Which kind of obviously feels completely wrong, but is what they do in the [docs](https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/execution/dataloader/).

Comment: try this plugin, it's a fairly complex and generic task to implement on your own. https://github.com/tfoxy/graphene-django-optimizer

Comment: that doesn't quite play in nicely with graphene-django-extras what I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Using a DataLoader is the correct approach but do `self.author_id` instead of `self.author.id`.

By calling `self.author.id` you're fetching the author for each book (one SQL query per author) then getting the `id` attribute from each author.

When you add the `author` ForeignKey to your `Book` model, behind the scenes, Django adds a column to the `books` table—`author_id`. You can pass this value to your DataLoader and have it fetch all the corresponding `Author`s in a single SQL query using a `SELECT IN`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#database-representation

You'll notice that the [Graphene Docs](https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/execution/dataloader/) are doing the same thing with `best_friend_id` in their example.